# Facebook page plugin not showing up in firefox?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, facebook

I embedded a facebook page plugin on a site I am working on. It loads fine on google chrome, but when I view the site in firefox it does not show up. Has anyone run into this problem and found a solution? Or am I just doing something wrong? Also, any advice on how can I make it responsive to screen size?

HTML:

```
<div class="col1">
  <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/CityofNewportRI/" data-width="500" data-height="450" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/CityofNewportRI/"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/CityofNewportRI/">City of Newport RI</a></blockquote></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.social-container .row1 .col1 .fb-page {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please ask only one question per topic (but a question asking general guidance on how to make a page responsive would be off-topic here -- too broad).

Comment: Do you have a link to where you have implemented this and it does not show? Adding custom css to override the behavior of the plugin could result in the plugin not showing.